# textbox with autocomplete doesn't excecute key_press event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, textbox

I have a textbox with the event of KeyPress to change to other textbox when Enter-key  is Pressed and it was working until I add an autocomplete property from the property panel on visual studio like:

> AutoCompleteCustomSource: Collection
>
> AutoCompleteMode: SuggestAppend
>
> AutoCompleteSource: CustomSource

Now autocomplete works but when I press enter it does not change to the other textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use event `KeyDown` instead. It works fine in my test.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```